# GUI question Java Netbeans assocoiating TextFields with numbers

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to learn  using gui on  netbeans. So basically i have 99 text fields, each one having the numbers from 1-99. All textfields have white backgrounds. I have an arrayList which stores numbers 1-99. I have a method which removes certain numbers (how i remove these numbers aren't important to my question).Then i have a method check(): that I want to do this

It will have a for loop going from 1-99 and I want to check all the  numbers that were deleted. If a number  was  deleted I want to make it's  corressponding label's  background red.

Heres my problem. How do I  associate each number with it's corressponding label. There's a lot of labels so doing a switch statement will take long. I thought I could make each label have the same name except with  their  corressponding  number  at the end,  ex.  TextField1, TextField2 and TextField99.

Then in a for loop i could do

```
for (int i=1;i<99;i++){
     String button = "TextField"+i;
      button.setBackGround(Color.Red);
}
```

but now I realize how stupid that was.

So is there anyway to associate each number with a label without using a switch statement

Comment: You mean without the loop ?

Comment: I mean in general. Like how do i connect the  number 6, to the textField with 6, and do this for 98 other numbers

Comment: You can associate an array of JTextFields with the numbers easily.  Java arrays are zero-based, so subtract one from the number to get the index to the particular JTextField.

Comment: Ah I see. Is there an easy way i Can assign the labels to a text array or do i have to go             array[0]=textLabel1, array[1]=textLabel2,......array[98]=textLabel99 for all of them?